# adding anchor to div via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarvagnya1/ET69q/

I have a bunch of HTML code which I want to make clickable. I can't edit the HTML so adding with jquery is the only option.

```
<div class="cont1">
   <div> Content1 </div>
   <div> Content 2 </div>
</div>
```

The div with class="cont1" has to be made clickable, please help

Comment: Please post your attempt before asking someone else to code it for you...

Comment: @A.Wolff: I tried with wrap, it didn't work, I though I was doing it wrong and there is some other function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4r5xf/)</kbd>

You can wrap you div with `a` tag

```
$('.cont1').wrap('<a href="http://google.com" class="link"/>');
```

CSS

```
.link {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: @RandomSeed with `OnClick` handler you can not use feature like  `target="_blank"`